# TypeScript Strange Value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I made a test with below code in TypeScript, the output for `console.log(this.userList);` are the same, is there any wrong in my code?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1 (click)='Test()'>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { 
  name = 'Angular'; 
  userList:User[]=[
    {id:1,name:"T1",isChecked:false},
    {id:2,name:"T2",isChecked:false},
    {id:3,name:"T3",isChecked:false}
  ];
  Test(){
    console.log(this.userList);
    this.userList.forEach((user)=>{
      user.isChecked=true;
    });
    console.log(this.userList);
  }
}

export interface User{
  id?:number,
  name?:string,
  age?:number,
  isChecked?:boolean
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not because of any issue with your code. It has to do with how the developer console handles objects. In developer console, when you expand an object it will show you the state the object is in currently.

To see the difference, you can try `JSON.stringify`-ing your object -- which will dump your current object as string:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.userList));
this.userList.forEach((user)=>{
  user.isChecked=true;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.userList));
```